# How to calculate the integral for coulomb potential?

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

I have an integral which drives me crazy since it takes forever for Mathematica to solve it. I am pretty sure it is the way I wrote it, but I do not know how to write it differently. I would appreciate it if somebody can help me with it.

Here is the function I defined:

```
   hardwaycoulomb[\[ScriptL]_, m1_, m2_, p1_, p2_] :=
   ( pott = (Sin[t] Sin[tp])/(
   Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
   1 - Cos[t] Cos[tp] - Cos[p] Cos[pp] Sin[t] Sin[tp] - 
   Sin[p] Sin[pp] Sin[t] Sin[tp]]) // Simplify;
  integ = 
  Conjugate[
  SphericalHarmonicY[\[ScriptL], m1, t, 
   p]] SphericalHarmonicY[\[ScriptL], p1, t, p] pott Conjugate[
  SphericalHarmonicY[\[ScriptL], m2, tp, 
   pp]] SphericalHarmonicY[\[ScriptL], p2, tp, pp] // Simplify;
  Integrate[
  integ, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {tp, 0, \[Pi]}, {pp, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}])
```

and I try to calculate

```
 hardwaycoulomb[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

but it takes forever to solve it.

Comment: A numerical attempt `hardwaycoulomb[\[ScriptL]_?NumericQ, m1_?NumericQ, m2_?NumericQ, 
  p1_?NumericQ, p2_?NumericQ] :=...` using `NIntegrate` results in a error message `Numerical integration converging`!

Comment: What reason do you have for believing your intragral is valid and has a closed form solution? Also, does "it takes forever for Mathematica to solve it" really mean that you are not getting a solution?

Comment: it is a coulomb potential, so I should get an answer for the interaction between two electrons on if they are on the surface of  a sphere. that's why I used spherical harmonics for the wave functions.

Comment: but I need to think about it more

Comment: the pott is the coulomb potential in spherical coordinate: 
 pott = (Abs[(Sin[t] Cos[p] - Sin[tp] Cos[pp])^2 + (Sin[t] Sin[p] - 
         Sin[tp] Sin[pp])^2 + (Cos[t] - Cos[tp])^2])^(-1/2  )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed with numerical method `hardwaycoulomb[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]=1` (with some error). Let define

```
pott = (Sin[t] Sin[tp])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
      1 - Cos[t] Cos[tp] - Cos[p] Cos[pp] Sin[t] Sin[tp] - 
       Sin[p] Sin[pp] Sin[t] Sin[tp]]);
integ = Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[L, m1, t, p]] SphericalHarmonicY[
     L, p1, t, p] pott Conjugate[
     SphericalHarmonicY[L, m2, tp, pp]] SphericalHarmonicY[L, p2, tp, 
     pp] // Simplify;
```

For particular case we have

```
int1 = integ /. {L -> 2, m1 -> 1, m2 -> 1, p1 -> 1, p2 -> 1}


NIntegrate[int1, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {tp, 
  0, \[Pi]}, {pp, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]

Out[]= 1.01343
```

But if we compute several times and averaged we got $1\pm .013$. For example

```
In[13]:= lst = 
 Table[NIntegrate[
   int1, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {tp, 0, \[Pi]}, {pp, 0, 
    2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"], {10}]

Out[13]= {0.999993, 0.991313, 1.01289, 0.996495, 1.01756, 1.01261, \
0.991081, 0.998455, 0.989598, 1.02531}

In[14]:= Mean[lst]

Out[14]= 1.00353

In[15]:= StandardDeviation[lst]

Out[15]= 0.0125934
```